# Error at defining a specific field in a Hive Query

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I have an Orion Context Broker connected with Cosmos by cygnus.

It works ok, I mean I send new elements to Context Broker and cygnus send them to Cosmos and save them in files.

The problem I have is when I try to do some searchs.

I start hive, and I see that there are some tables created related with the files that cosmos have created, so I launch some querys.

The simple one works fine:

```
select * from Table_name;
```

Hive doesn't launch any mapReduce jobs.

but when I want to filter, join, count, or get only some fields. That is what happens:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = JOB_NAME, Tracking URL = JOB_DETAILS_URL
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop job  -kill JOB_NAME
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2015-07-08 14:35:12,723 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-07-08 14:35:38,943 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = JOB_NAME with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: TASK_NAME (and more) from job JOB_NAME

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201409031055_6337_m_000000

URL: TASK_DETAIL_URL
-----

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
```

I have found that the files that are created by Cygnus has difference between tha other files, because in the case of the cygnus, they have to be deserialize with a jar.

So, I have the doubt if in those cases I have to apply any MapReduce method or if is already any general method to do this.

Comment: Orion data persisted by Cygnus within Cosmos is written in JSON format, and Cygnus creates the associated Hive tables with a JSON serde (serializer/deserializer in Hive jargon) that allows accessing the data. Anyway, which version of Cygnus are you using?

Comment: The version of Cygnus is 0.7.1. I know that the data is saved in JSON format, and it is used JSON serde, but my question is in the moment of do a search. Hive try to apply a MapReduce and it fails, I supose that its because the data has JSON format and you have to use a MapReduce specific method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing any Hive sentence, do this:

```
hive> add jar /usr/local/hive-0.9.0-shark-0.8.0-bin/lib/json-serde-1.1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

If you are using Hive through JDBC, execute is as any other sentence:

```
Connection con = ...
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("add jar /usr/local/hive-0.9.0-shark-0.8.0-bin/lib/json-serde-1.1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar");
stmt.close();
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ...");
```